# Building libxml2 without root privilages

Tags: makefile, libxml2

I am trying to build libxml2 on a high performance cluster where I don't have root privileges.

I do this with (first loading possible dependencies as instructed by someone who managed to install libxml2 on the same hpc using the same dependencies, many/all are probably not required but they are for other things that I will run)

```
module load gcc/10.3.0-gcc-9.4.0 cmake/3.23.1-gcc-10.3.0 openmpi/4.1.3-gcc-10.3.0-python3+-chk-version openblas/0.3.20-gcc-10.3.0 python/3.8.12-gcc-9.4.0
module unload libxml2/2.9.12-gcc-10.3.0 libiconv/1.16-gcc-10.3.0
```

followed by:

```
wget ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-sources-2.9.10.tar.gz
tar -xvzf  libxml2-sources-2.9.10.tar.gz libxml2-2.9.10/
cd libxml2-2.9.10/
./configure --prefix=$HOME/install
make
make install
```

This produces the following error:

```
Making install in python
make[2]: Entering directory '/users/anonymous/libxml2-2.9.10/python'
make install-recursive
make[3]: Entering directory '/users/anonymous/libxml2-2.9.10/python'
Making install in .
make[4]: Entering directory '/users/anonymous/libxml2-2.9.10/python'
make[5]: Entering directory '/users/anonymous/libxml2-2.9.10/python'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
/usr/bin/mkdir -p '/users/anonymous/install/share/doc/libxml2-python-2.9.10'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 TODO '/users/anonymous/install/share/doc/libxml2-python-2.9.10'
/usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 drv_libxml2.py libxml2.py '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages'
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/drv_libxml2.py': Permission denied
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libxml2.py': Permission denied
make[5]: *** [Makefile:667: install-dist_pythonDATA] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory '/users/anonymous/libxml2-2.9.10/python'
make[4]: *** [Makefile:860: install-am] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory '/users/anonymous/libxml2-2.9.10/python'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:694: install-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/users/anonymous/libxml2-2.9.10/python'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:854: install] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/users/anonymous/libxml2-2.9.10/python'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1479: install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/users/anonymous/libxml2-2.9.10'
make: *** [Makefile:1786: install] Error 2
```

It seems weird that it is trying to write to a directory `/usr/lib/python3/` where I don't have write permissions even though I specified a different prefix directory.

Any idea what I could do to resolve this error?

Comment: You probably don't need the Python bindings, so disable them with `./configure --without-python`.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems weird that it is trying to write to a directory /usr/lib/python3/ where I don't have write permissions even though I specified a different prefix directory.

It is very likely trying to write there because that's the library directory of the Python installation it located and used at build time.

Supposing that you do not want to, or cannot, disable building the Python components in the first place, a reasonably good alternative would be to install to a staging area that is writable to you, then move the files from there to the appropriate places.  You can do this by specifying a suitable `DESTDIR` variable to `make install`:

```
mkdir -p ~/staging
make install DESTDIR=~/staging
```

You then can (and should) move files and folders from `~/staging` to the appropriate places in `$HOME/install` or elsewhere.

Note well that `DESTDIR` serves a different purpose than do `configure's` installation-location options such as `--prefix`.  They are not interchangeable.  The latter indicate where files are meant to be installed, and that can affect how they are built.  `DESTDIR` does not affect how files are built, just where `make install` actually puts them.  If they are sensitive to installation location -- and some software is -- then the software will not work correctly there.

Comment: What does moving them to "appropriate places (...) elsewhere" mean. If "elsewhere" is ever the appropriate place then it sounds like I'm always in trouble. I cannot write in the python directory. Not during the `make` but also not after. So it is a requirement of the libxml2 build to put files in places like your python installation? That seems weird and inconvenient (in this case it means I have to build a separate version of python for it to alter). Also I tried an older version now and it build successfully without ever trying to build to the python directory.

Comment: So the older versions didn't seem to need to do this. Any idea why this inconvenience was added?

Comment: @Kvothe, "elsewhere" means the intended installation location as specified to `configure`, so in your case, that would be various folders under `$HOME/install`.  The directory structure under `~/staging` will convey where, specifically.  Those Python files are a wildcard, though, and there may be others.  The build system's idea of where those need to go might be different from where they actually should go.

Comment: @Kvothe, I can't be sure what older versions actually did do.  For example, maybe they had exactly the same installation behavior, but disabled building the Python components by default, so that you or others did not notice.  Also, it might be that the current version has `configure` options that would mitigate the effect, such as by allowing you to give a different destination for the Python modules.  To be clear, though: it's not unreasonable to try to install Python modules into the library of the Python implementation with which they were built.

Comment: thanks! (Disagree on the reasonableness of installing in the python direction though. Most people building libxml2 themselves will do this because there are issues with root privilages. Therefore it is clearly not reasonable to assume the build can just write anywhere it likes. And it means I would now have to build a new python just for it to be able to alter.)

Comment: @Kvothe, I think you have some misapprehensions there.  In the first place, the installation stage of a conventional build system is not designed around or for people installing without having system privileges.  Your case is a comparatively rare one, and what support there is for it is incidental.  In the second place, *in no way* do you need to build a new Python.  You do need to figure out where to put the built Python modules, and to put them there manually, but that's not at all the same thing.

Comment: what do you mean figure out where to put them? Can I put them anywhere or should they be in the python directory where the build tries to put them. If the latter I obviously can't put them there manually right. I can only put them in the local directory where I have write access (which obviously doesn't contain any python files since I didn't build python).

Comment: For simplicity you can assume I have only one directory where I can write which is the prefix one that I just created and where most of the files successfully went. Can I just copy the files that using your methods are created in staging to that directory?

Comment: @Kvothe, I suggest you actually try that build.  I anticipate that seeing what it produces for yourself will help you more than any description I can give.  But yes, you can copy the contents of the staging directory into your target directory via an appropriate `cp -r` or `rsync -a` or similar command.  The full directory structure will be in staging.  But you do still have to attend to the question of whether all the designated locations actually serve your purposes.  Especially the destination where the Python modules are placed.